# ERP integration with Magento 2.3

Tags: magento2, integration

I want to integrate my ERP with my magento 2.3. I would like to know the best practice to be follow. What are the requirements from ERP and magento to communicate with each other. If any one have done this kind of integration please help me out. Is there any document or anything that can give complete explanation. Is there any extension? This is something which i have come acrossed for the first time. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: which ERP you want to integrate ???

Comment: @BirenPatel Consider it as any ERP. I have not received ERP details yet from client

Comment: Example : if you want to connect Acumatica,Orderhive etc ERP with magento then there is an extension.

Comment: So it's basically depends on ERP

Comment: @BirenPatel In common what these extensions basically manage in terms of exchanging information between two?

Comment: It will manage attribute,product,customer,category,order sync etc...

Comment: @BirenPatel Thanx. Is there any extension that supports all ERP?

Comment: No , Bcoz the request and response for the sync call is different for different ERP's...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103874/discussion-between-nafisa-and-biren-patel).